# How to Overcome Footnotemark Abberations When Using Both the Footmisc Package and the Electrum Font

Tags: pdftex, footnotes, footmisc

When using the `footmisc` package with the default font (Computer Modern, I presume), I am able to produce the following output:

[image]

with the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{perpage} 
\MakePerPage{footnote} 
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

%\usepackage[lf]{electrum}

    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    A sentence.\footnote{First footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Second footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Third footnote}
    A sentence.\footnote{Fourth footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Fifth footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Sixth footnote}
    \end{document}
```

However, when I invoke the `electrum` font, some of the footnotemarks become altered considerably---such as the first one which resembles more a dot than an asterisk:

[image]

At first, I thought it might have something to do with the `electrum` font, but when I use that font without the `footmisc` package, there is little or no change in the footnotemarks.

QUESTION: How may I use both the `footmisc` package with the `electrum` font compiled with PDFlatex so that the footnotemarks appear as originally displayed? I especially want to make sure that the first footnote appears (on each page) as an asterisk and not a dot. (If not, how may I magnify the size of the footnotemarks when using both of the aforesaid packages so that the tiny, subtle electrum asterisk is not so hard to distinguish?)

Thank you.

Comment: your picture is not very clear, but I don't see a problem, or a difference if I disable footmisc. Is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Unfortunately, I do not know how to enhance the image when posting the question so that the asterisk vs. dot is more clearly visible. Perhaps I can modify the question with a different image. Let me work on it and see what I can do.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I have not been able to magnify the size of the footnotes; however, I have modified the question. Upon magnification, the electrum font coupled with the footmisc package produces an asterisk, but one at least to my eyes is hard to distinguish. I am hoping to implement some kind of a remedy to make the asterisk more visible---for when it appears in small print, it is difficult in the document I am working on to tell that it is a footnotemark. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The `electrum` font's asterisk is not a dot but does not look as spiky as the default's asterisk. You get what you ask for. It's a whole different question if you want to change the `electrum` asterisk to something more spicy. --- GOM